# Why is superuser.com also served on port 8080?

Tags: support

I noticed this while Googling for ["Notice removed Draw attention"](https://www.google.com/search?q="Notice%20removed%20Draw%20attention"); all of the superuser.com results have an explicit port in their URL.

[image: su:8080]

Indeed it works.

- http://superuser.com:8080/
- http://meta.superuser.com:8080/

Out of [all](http://stackoverflow.com:8080) [the](http://serverfault.com:8080) [other](http://stackexchange.com:8080) [SE](http://japanese.stackexchange.com:8080) sites I have checked, Super User is the only one consistently accessible through this port. Server Fault also responded with a 200 after a few tries.

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' http://superuser.com:8080/
200
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' http://serverfault.com:8080/
200
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' --connect-timeout 10 http://stackoverflow.com:8080/
000
```

1. Is this something intentional? What's the reason behind it?
2. Is it possible to make these URLs not to come up in search results? It gives the impression that the site is running on a development server.

Comment: ServerFault loads over 8080 for me.

Comment: It did for me too just now. Maybe this should be migrated to meta.se.